# Change g_timeout_add_seconds to something with 0.5 second

Tags: gtk, glib

```
g_timeout_add_seconds(1, (GSourceFunc) update_status_tray, NULL);
```

The above code will refresh the status tray every second, but I need to refresh it every half second. How to change this line to get 0.5 second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
g_timeout_add(500, (GSourceFunc) update_status_tray, NULL);
```